# $.ajax success not executing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, json, jquery

I have in my .js file a function that call a webservices method called getStudents:

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "white student list")]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<Job> getStudents(long classId)
    {
        return (new classManager()).getStudents(classId);
    }
```

the method is callled like:

```
function loadStudents() {

    var parameters = JSON.stringify({ 'classId': 0 });

    alert(parameters);

    $("#ProcessingDiv").show('fast', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myWebService.asmx/getStudents",
            data: parameters,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                  $("#ProcessingDiv").hide();
                  var students= response.d;
                  alert('yes');
            },

            error: function(request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
            ,
            failure: function(msg) {
                alert('somethin went wrong' + msg);
            }
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    loadStudents();
});
```

when i debug,the service web method is executed successfully but i don't get my alert('yes') and neither msg error.

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you looked what is in response? (With Firebug or Chrome dev tools)

Comment: With firebug you can look at your ajax request, and at response you get - maybe there is no response at all? As i assume, you should get list of JS objects with props from `Job` class - but i'm not into asp.net, so I don't know how serialization works there.

Comment: Your code looks correct. One shot in the dark is to make sure that your web service class (not the method, but the containing class) has the `[ScriptService]` attribute.

Comment: Thank you guys ,firebug solved my pb.it was a pb in a property of the object

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning (serialized to JSON) List of objects, then in response you will get JS array of JS objects, so (assuming `Job` has property `p`) try `response[0].p` for `p` value from first element.

**note:** I don't know ASP.NET, so maybe response is serialized in another way, thats where tools like Firebug (or other browsers Dev tools) are extremely useful - because you can look how exactly you'r http requests and responses looks like.

**ps.** And change `alert` to `console.log` and look for logs in Firebug console - its better than `alert` in many, many ways ;]